# How to compute linear combination of columns in pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do the following computation:

```
priors['user_product'] = priors.eval('product_id + user_id*100000')
```

where `user_product` is a new column that i want to generate.
However the computation takes a lot of time since the priors dataframe is huge(has 3000000 rows, to be precise)

Comment: `priors['user_product'] = priors['product_id'] + priors['user_id']*100000` is slowier?

Comment: It took forever to compute via pandas,by the method you mentioned, for some reason. Eval also resulted in problems. Looking into pandas documentation, I realised eval using numexpr as a backend if the library is installed. So installing numexpr immediately resulted in much faster computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want fast, you can use `numpy` or `numexpr` or normal `pandas`

**`pandas`**

```
priors['user_product'] = priors.product_id + 100000 * priors.user_id
```

**`numpy`**

```
priors['user_product'] = priors.product_id.values + 100000 * priors.user_id.values
```

**`numexpr`**

```
pid = priors.product_id.values
uid = priors.user_id.values
priors['user_product'] = numexpr.evaluate('pid + 100000 * uid')
```

**Timing**

```
n = 3000000
priors = pd.DataFrame(dict(product_id=np.random.rand(n), user_id=np.random.rand(n)))

%timeit priors['user_product'] = priors.eval('product_id + 100000 * user_id')
%timeit priors['user_product'] = priors.product_id.values + 100000 * priors.user_id.values
%timeit priors['user_product'] = priors.product_id + 100000 * priors.user_id

10 loops, best of 3: 31.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop

%%timeit
pid = priors.product_id.values
uid = priors.user_id.values
priors['user_product'] = numexpr.evaluate('pid + 100000 * uid')

100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop
```